# MVVMCROSS Wpf Setup

Tags: c#, wpf, cross-platform, mvvmcross

ANSWER: Just update the packages and make sure the packages in the PCL and WPF are the same.

I'm having trouble creating the setup class for my wpf project. I have iOS, Android and WinPhone working. But in the setup class for the wpf project I'm getting this error:

[image]

Please note that `ProjectGaea.Mobile` is my PCL that I've reference in other projects such as iOS and Android.

I've also installed the mvvmcross.core nuget package.
I have also referenced the pcl in the wpf project.
So what could be causing the problem?

Comment: What version of Mvx have you installed? Judging by the error message, it may be a version miss-match? One running pre version Mvx version 4 still with "Cirrious" namespace and the other running a newer version?

Comment: Yes! You were definitely  right. There is definitely a difference between the  references. The PCL has Cirrious references but the Wpf project has Mvvmcross references.. I update the packages and it works now. Thank you so so much for helping out. Really appreciate it.

Comment: Glad to hear it's sorted now.

Answer (score 0):

The packages in the PCL and The Wpf Project need to be the same version.